# No bluetooth scan result

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to scan for any BLE device broadcasting in the area, and display it in a table form in the android app. However, my app could not detect any BLE device when other apps from Google Play Store could.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

//Bluetooth Management
private BluetoothAdapter btAdapter;
private LeDeviceListAdapter mLeDeviceListAdapter;
private boolean mScanning;

// Set the enable bluetooth code
private final static int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 0;

// LOG Messages
private final static String DEBUG_TAG = "";

private static final int SCAN_INTERVAL_MS = 10000;

//Handler
private Handler myHandler;

//Testing For ListView
static String[] words = {"one", "two", "three"};


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myHandler = new Handler();
    //Check whether BLE is supported on the device(can selectively disable BLE-related features)
    if(!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "ble_not_supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
    }

    final BluetoothManager btManager =
            (BluetoothManager)getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
    btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();

    //Check if Bluetooth Adapter is present in the device
    if(btAdapter == null)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error : Bluetooth not supported", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "No bluetooth available");
        finish();
        return;
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ble_Device_List);
    listView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return null;
        }
    });              
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // check for Bluetooth enabled on each resume
    if (btAdapter != null && !btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    //Initialise list view adapter
    mLeDeviceListAdapter = new LeDeviceListAdapter();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ble_Device_List);
    listView.setAdapter(mLeDeviceListAdapter);

    scanLeDevice(true);
}


@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    scanLeDevice(false);
    mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

}

@Override
public void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    btAdapter = null;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request_enable_bt, int result_enable_bt, Intent data) {
    if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_OK) {
        //Display "Turn On" message
        Toast.makeText(this, "Turned On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Turn On Toast Success!");

        // Display device name and MAC Address
        BluetoothManager btManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        btAdapter = btManager.getAdapter();
        String address = btAdapter.getAddress();
        String name = btAdapter.getName();
        String toastText = name + " : " + address;
        Toast.makeText(this, toastText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Device Name and Address Toast Success!");
    } else if (result_enable_bt == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Didn't Turn On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Turn Off Toast Success!");

        finish();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(request_enable_bt, result_enable_bt, data);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    if(!mScanning){
        menu.findItem(R.id.scan).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.stop).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.info).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setActionView(null);
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Menu_mScanning = 0");
    }

    else{
        menu.findItem(R.id.scan).setVisible(false);
        menu.findItem(R.id.stop).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.exit).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.info).setVisible(true);
        menu.findItem(R.id.refresh).setActionView(
                R.layout.actionbar_indeterminate_progress);
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Menu_mScanning = 1");
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.scan:
              if(mLeDeviceListAdapter.getCount() >0)
              mLeDeviceListAdapter.clear();

            scanLeDevice(true);
            Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Scan button pressed!");
            break;
        case R.id.stop:
            scanLeDevice(false);
            break;

        case R.id.info:
            Intent reminder_Intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Reminder.class);
            startActivity(reminder_Intent);
            break;

        case  R.id.exit:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}

private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback leScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device);
                 mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
};


private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "Scanning enabled!");
        // Stops scanning after a pre-defined scan period.
        myHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScanning = false;
                Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "scanLeEnable_mScanning = 0");
                btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        }, SCAN_INTERVAL_MS);

        mScanning = true;
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "scanLeEnable_mScanning = 1");

        btAdapter.startLeScan(leScanCallback);
    } else {
        mScanning = false;
        Log.i("DEBUG_TOAST", "scanLeNotEnable_mScanning = 0");

        btAdapter.stopLeScan(leScanCallback);
    }
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
}

//Adapter for holding devices found through scanning
private class LeDeviceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
    private LayoutInflater mInflator;

    public LeDeviceListAdapter() {
        super();
        mLeDevices = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
        mInflator = MainActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
    }

    public void addDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mLeDevices.contains(device)) {
            mLeDevices.add(device);
        }
    }

    public BluetoothDevice getDevice(int position) {
        return mLeDevices.get(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mLeDevices.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mLeDevices.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mLeDevices.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null){
            mInflator =
                    (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflator.inflate(R.layout.listitem_device, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.deviceAddress = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_address);
            Log.i("LISTVIEW_1", "1" );
            viewHolder.deviceName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.device_name);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else{
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        BluetoothDevice device = mLeDevices.get(position);
        final String deviceName = device.getName();
        if(deviceName != null && deviceName.length()>0){
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(deviceName);
        Log.i("LISTVIEW_1", "2" );
        }
        else
            viewHolder.deviceName.setText(R.string.unknown_device);
        viewHolder.deviceAddress.setText(device.getAddress());
        return convertView;
    }

}
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView deviceAddress, deviceName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try putting a log on your LeScanCallbak? If so it is logging?

Comment: I placed a log each at add mLeDeviceListAdapter.addDevice(device) and  mLeDeviceListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), and the logcat shows that these two steps have been reached during running.

Comment: Tell me which device you are using as client and which device you are using as Gatt server

Comment: Erm, I am not using any services, as I only hope to obtain the beacon's(Broadcaster) address and name. If this is the case, do I need to do anything to the GATT?

Comment: Which Android version are you using on your device?

Comment: I'm using Android version 5.0.2

Comment: Ok, so you said according to your logs, your ScanCallback is called at least? Then the error has to be in displaying it, or did I misunderstand your comment before?

Comment: Yes, my ScanCallback is called. I have also suspected that there might be error with displaying the information. Does it have anything to do with me using AppCompatActivity instead of List Activity?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting two different adapters in the listview. One is in **onResume** and different one in **onCreate**, You said scanCallback is getting called, this mean there is issue in displaying the item.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I removed the listadapter in OnCreate, changed the activity from AppCompatActivity to ListActivity and did a log.i for each code in the defining of the class. However, I realised that the app could not detect any device, even though I have included most of the codes from the open source code DeviceScanActivity from Android.

Comment: I've solved my problem. Forgot to put a '!' in my addDevice function

Comment: Cool. It was indeed a UI issue and not a gatt issue.